# sonata admin filter doctrine_orm_callback

Tags: php, sonata-admin

I have a filter that will filter how many tags that item have. But I cant get it working it will give me an error:

> The query returned multiple rows. Change the query or use a different result function like getScalarResult().

In my Item Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="item", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $tags;
```

In my Tag Entity

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Item", inversedBy="tags")
 */
private $clip;
```

In the configureDatagridFilters in ItemAdmin

```
->add('tag', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(
            'label' => 'Keywords',
            'callback' => function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                if (!isset($value['value'])) {
                    return;
                }

                $operators = array(
                    NumberType::TYPE_EQUAL            => '=',
                    NumberType::TYPE_GREATER_EQUAL    => '>=',
                    NumberType::TYPE_GREATER_THAN     => '>',
                    NumberType::TYPE_LESS_EQUAL       => '<=',
                    NumberType::TYPE_LESS_THAN        => '<',
                );

                $operator = $operators[$value['value']['type']];

                $queryBuilder->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.%s', $alias, $field), 't');
                $queryBuilder->having('COUNT(ct) '.$operator.' :count');
                $queryBuilder->groupBy('t.item');
                $queryBuilder->setParameter('count', $value['value']);
            },
            'field_type' => 'number',
        ))
```